# Can Kruskal-Wallis be used for discrete data?

Tags: r, kruskal-wallis-test, hypothesis-testing

I have a data frame with variables that are counts, nominal (two groups) and continuous. Two of the continuous variable follow a normal distribution; the counts variables do not follow a normal distribution. The samples are independent.

Can I use a Kruskal-Wallis test to check the difference in the means of the two groups?
I am lost regarding if non-parametric tests can be used for discrete data (specifically, counts). Moreover, there are a lot of ties in the data (it's an activity data frame, where the entrances and exits of birds in nests were counted periodically).

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use the KW test with discrete values, and I think that's typically the case for most (all?) tests. There's nothing special about discrete values in data ... because what typically matters is the precision of your value rather than whether its a real or an integer, and real life measurements don't have infinite precision so data is never really "continuous". It'd be different if you were fitting distributions since some distributions exist especially for count data ... but even then modelling discrete data that looks Gaussian as Gaussian even though it can't possibly be is pretty common. On the KW topic, more precisely (from Wikipedia):

`If the researcher can make the assumptions of an identically shaped and scaled distribution for all groups, except for any difference in medians, then the null hypothesis is that the medians of all groups are equal, and the alternative hypothesis is that at least one population median of one group is different from the population median of at least one other group.`

So you can use it to compare medians under the assumption that both samples come from the same distribution. @dave points out that IF the distributions are the same, comparing medians and means would be the same BUT if the distributions are not the same than comparing medians and means may NOT be the same. Therefore, one cannot assume that this test is a comparison of means because it is a valid comparison of medians.

Comment: There actually is something quite special about discrete data: the possibility of ties.  Many rank-based nonparametric procedures, like the KW, will fall apart unless ties are properly accounted for and corrected.  Extreme numbers of ties can render them powerless.

Comment: On the assumption that continuous values are less likely to produce ties? That's about precision and range. Measuring height in $\mu m$ is discrete but less likely to produce ties than measuring heigh in metres to two decimal places.

Comment: If the distributions have identical shapes and scales, then the null hypothesis that the medians are equal is equivalent to a null that the means are equal. // Continuous distributions produce ties with probability $0$.

Comment: There are a lot of ties in my data. Would a Wilcoxon test be better then? And I updated the questions to clarify a few things.

Comment: @IsaBragantini Much like a t-test is ANOVA with two groups, Wilcoxon (Mann-Whitney U) is KW with two groups.

Comment: @Dave but what about the ties issue? Additionally, Wilcoxon doesn't assume equal variances?

Comment: @IsaBragantini I would call those distinct questions: 1) What exactly are the assumptions of the Wilcoxon MWU test? 2) How to test for a difference in means when there are many ties in the data? Cross Validated operates on a strict Q&A basis, where distinct questions get compartmented in distinct posts in order to organize discussions. Please feel free to post those two! (I suspect both are duplicates, so perhaps search around here.)

Comment: @Dave i think you're failing to distiniguish the difference between a continuous distribution and a non discrete value with limited precision. There is no such thing as an infinite precision measurement. The probability of your actual data having ties is certainly not zero, and the likelihood is governed by precision not whether its an integer or a float.

Comment: @Dave as a separate point something like the Cauchy distribution doesn't even define a mean but it does have a median ... so in the general case it isn't true that a test of the mean will be a test of the median even if the distributions are the same.

Comment: Fair point that the mean has to exist for my comment to be 100% correct, but do you see why, with the assumption of equal scale and shape, different medians is the same as different 75th percentiles or 11th percentiles (or mean, if it exists)? $\text{//}$ Your edit, the paragraph that mentions me, is problematic.

Comment: @Dave, I do! And I do agree... I'd be grateful if you said more about why you think my edit is problematic.

Comment: 1) I do not follow what you mean about if the distributions are the same. 2) When the shapes are different, Wilcoxon MWU is not quite a test of median equality.